# How to correctly setup Linker in Eclipse IDE 4.8.0M4 for ffmpeg development (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, eclipse, git, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I am using Eclipse IDE 4.8.0M4 on Ubunto 16.04. I try to compile the code from a FFmpeg tutorial on GitHUB: (https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial/blob/master/0_hello_world.c). For setting up FFmpeg in Eclipse i used this guide:(https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Setup_Eclipse_IDE_for_FFmpeg_(Linux)).

The header files and libaries are all in the folder /home/git/ffmpeg. (e.g. avcodec.h and libavcodec.a is in the folder /home/git/ffmpeg/libavcodec). Included libs: -lavcodec -lpostproc -lz -llzma -lrt -lavfilter -lswresample -lavdevice -lswscale -lavutil -lavformat

Console output:

```
12:34:30 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project ffmpeg_test ****
make all 
Building target: ffmpeg_test
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc -L/home/git/ffmpeg/libavcodec -L/home/git/ffmpeg/libavformat -o "ffmpeg_test"  ./src/simpletest.o   -lavcodec -lpostproc -lz -llzma -lrt -lavfilter -lswresample -lavdevice -lswscale -lavutil -lavformat
./src/simpletest.o: In function `main':
/home/boergi/eclipse-workspace/ffmpeg_test/Debug/../src/simpletest.c:141: undefined reference to `avcodec_parameters_to_context'
/home/boergi/eclipse-workspace/ffmpeg_test/Debug/../src/simpletest.c:163: undefined reference to `av_packet_alloc'
/home/boergi/eclipse-workspace/ffmpeg_test/Debug/../src/simpletest.c:194: undefined reference to `av_packet_free'
./src/simpletest.o: In function `decode_packet':
/home/boergi/eclipse-workspace/ffmpeg_test/Debug/../src/simpletest.c:214: undefined reference to `avcodec_send_packet'
/home/boergi/eclipse-workspace/ffmpeg_test/Debug/../src/simpletest.c:225: undefined reference to `avcodec_receive_frame'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:30: recipe for target 'ffmpeg_test' failed
make: *** [ffmpeg_test] Error 1

12:34:31 Build Finished (took 519ms)
```

I found out that "int avcodec_parameters_to_context(AVCodecContext *codec, const AVCodecParameters *par)" is defined in utils.c (also in the /libavcodec folder), but i don't know what can i do to get this running.

```
boergi@Ubuntu-b:~/git/ffmpeg$ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version N-89895-g7723750 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 20160609
configuration: 
libavutil      56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
libavcodec     58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
libavformat    58.  5.101 / 58.  5.101
libavdevice    58.  0.101 / 58.  0.101
libavfilter     7. 11.101 /  7. 11.101
libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
```

Comment: Are you sure you followed the instructions for ffmpeg in eclipse correctly, including the point https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Setup_Eclipse_IDE_for_FFmpeg_(Linux)#CreatenewCprojectusingexistingFFmpegssourcecode ? Something is strange with your folders. Why is the ffmpeg library in this folder `/home/git/ffmpeg/`? Is _git_ a vlid user in your ubuntu? The git repo should be under your home directory, like `/home/boergi/git/ffmpeg/`

Comment: Are you aware that 4.8.0M4 is a Milestome build? Eclipse 4.6 will not be fully released until June 2018. 4.7.2 is the current release.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I now have version 4.7.2 of eclipse, and i updated the link of the lib. When building, i get now much more 'undefined reference' errors for the different libaries, e.g. `/home/boergi/git/ffmpeg//libavformat/rtmpdigest.c:45: undefined reference to av_hmac_update'`. The strange thing is, that in the .c file i get instructions to the ffmpeg function when my mouse is on it, so it works somehow?